# Python: string to hexa

Tags: python

I would like to convert a string containing an hexadecimal value (ex: `12ab`) to that hexadecimal value (ex: `0x12ab`) in python.

How could I do?

Comment: Just add "0x" to the front of it?

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
   i = int('12ab', 16)
   # 4779
   hex(i)
   # '0x12ab'
```

Comment: And what about the other way? From hex to string?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the string, it would be trivial:

```
your_hexa_value = '12ab'
answer = '0x' your_hexa_value
```

But if you want the numeric value (which I think you want),

```
int(your_hexa_value, 16)
```

would suffice. Notice, that internally, all numbers are represented in binary, so their base doesn't matter:

```
>>> 10 + 0x10 + 010  # 10 + 16 + 8
>>> 34
```